# I want to stop the AVAudioRecorder when duration gets 5 mins

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new in ios development.I want to stop the avaudiorecorder when duration gets 5 mins.How to stop the avaudiorecorder automatically the duration gets over. How to do this.

Comment: see https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: using Timer or perform selector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this code to call the recorder stop function exactly after 5 seconds.When started recording add this code to that.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(stoprecord)withObject:nil afterDelay:5.0];
```

in the `stoprecord` function

```
-(void) stoprecord
{
  [audioRecorder stop];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use

```
    [audioRecorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration];
```

Comment: How to stop the avaudiorecorder automatically the audiorecorder duration gets over 5 mins

Comment: I used this [audioRecorder recordForDuration:5.0];But AVAudioRecorder is continuously recording the audio

Comment: Then there will be another problem this methods works for me..after 5.0s the - (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag; will be called

Comment: Now i used this (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag; but it is not stop the AVAudioRecorder. Give the sample code.Thank u.

Comment: have you add delegate of the AVAudioRecorderDelegate?